# How to set button color with changing font family styles in draft.js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I have Editor like this with three buttons and text area,
How can i set button `bg color: grey` with changing font text styles,

```
<Col>
    <span className = ""></span>
    <div>
    <button onMouseDown = { e => { _onUnderlineClick(e) } }>U</button>
    <button onMouseDown = { e => { _onBoldClick(e)} }>B</button>
    <button onMouseDown = { e => { _onItalicClick(e)} }><em>I</em></button>
    </div>
    <Editor editorState={editorState}
        onChange={onEnterText} handleBeforeInput={handleBeforeInput} handlePastedText={handlePastedText} handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommand} keyBindingFn={keyBindingFn}
        readOnly = {e}
    />
</Col>
```

[image: DraftJS]

button color must chnage while clicking on button, as well as with backspace when draftJS text style get changed dynamically, wthat time as well

Comment: @JiangYD yeah i do read

Comment: i am saying button colors not text style, both are independent

Comment: You're right.  Then `getcurrentinlinestyle()` will help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use state variable for styling and when your event handler called .you can change your state and this will automatically chnage style of your buttons.
so for example.
you want to chnage the style of button dynamically.

```
const [btnSty,setSty]=useState("property value")//set default propert value
const handleMouse=()=>{
setSty("set here")//property you want to set dynamically
}
<button onMouseDown = {handleMouse} style={{anyProperty:{btnSty}}>B</button>
```